# Item not available for purchase error message when using app with different version

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I have my app on Google play with version 2.2, and as a result of the latest restriction that we have to target API 26+, I published my updates on my Facebook page. But the problem is, that people using the updates (With higher version than 2.2) can't purchase the items. It shows Item not available for purchase error. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Google wanna make sure that if you are using their IAP you must add the application and its latest updates on their store, otherwise IAP won't work as a result of version code differences.

This is not good and not practical, why?

Because sometimes users don't update their apps, yet they are still using the app and want to purchase items.

Answer (score 0):

You published a downloadable APK in Facebook ?

Take in account that if your app has Google Play App Signing enabled on the developer console then the signature key of the APK you upload to play store for an app release is different than the key of the app the users install from the Play Store, the Developer Console changes it.

Then Android identifies both app (the installed from Play Store and the installed from an APK out of Play Store) as different apps, then the installed from the APK can't buy the items of the PLay Store app

The solution is to publish the update as a new release in the Developer Console

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Google Play App Signing

Comment: Knowing that when I installed the same version available on Google play from my Facebook page, it worked as expected and items are available for purchase.

Comment: Google Play App Signing enabled is the default for new apps,if it is not disabled before the first  release then it is enabled forever

Comment: I disabled it first time I uploaded my app

Comment: I didn't upload a signing key to their servers

Comment: Why are you releasing the update on Facebook and not from Play Store ?

Comment: "as a result of the latest restriction that we have to target API 26+, I published my updates on my Facebook page" ... I have to target a lower API version for now.